# not being awarded playstyles

Tags: splinter-cell-blacklist

In Splinter cell blacklist I'm not being awarded playstyles (ghost, panther, assault) all the time.

For example, I just finished Private Estate with > 10000 ghost style points, and did not get the ghost style for the mission.

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 10,000 points is more than the target number for that mission (check the mission briefing to make sure), there are some indications on other sites that the mission might be bugged.

For example, on another forum someone has complained about getting 10,000+ panther points on Private Estate and not being awarded gold.